# mod a Functions for Wp All Import

Tags: woocommerce

i need to ad to wp all import the field "_ebay_ean" for every variations, i finded this functions:

```
    <?php
/**
 * ==================================
 * Filter: wp_all_import_variation_taxonomies
 * ==================================
 *
 * Can be used to add taxonomies to WooCommerce product variations.
 *
 *
 * @param $taxonomies array - List of taxonomies.
 */
add_filter( 'wp_all_import_variation_taxonomies', 'wpai_wp_all_import_variation_taxonomies', 10, 1 );
function wpai_wp_all_import_variation_taxonomies( $taxonomies ){
        if ( ! in_array( 'my_taxonomy_name', $taxonomies ) ) $taxonomies[] = 'my_taxonomy_name';
        return $taxonomies;
}
```

is there a way to make this functions working to add for every variations imported to add the _ebay_ean field that must be one of value of my xml?

Comment: tryed with 'code' add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'update_variations_sku', 100 );
function update_variations_sku(){
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $results2 = array();
    $limit = 2500; // Number of variations to process

    $query = $product->id;

        $parent_sku = get_post_meta( $parent_id, '_sku', true );
        foreach($variation_ids as $variation_id){
            update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_ebay_ean', $parent_sku );
        }
} but dont work

Comment: Finally o found a solution on my site https://shop.outletscarpeonline.it